# SPA AWS Future Release Management

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, release-management, aws-devops

I am working on IOT device project, where my SPA is hosted on IOT devices (android tab). My FE is on angular and uses lambda and dynamodb for the backend and DB.

We went live for 300 devices from AUS and are going live for the UK with 200 devices this week.

For the next release, we have a few functionality changes which require the device cache clear and reboot (which we can be done remotely and in bulk). Device cache and reboot will take few mins for each device to complete and for all 500 device it would take very long time.

Need help with the plan to deploy the changes on the basis of geo-location. Can anyone help me how I can achieve this?

AWS resources being used:
R53,
cloudFront,
S3,
Lambda,
DYnamoDB.